# ScrollView apenas no textView desejado

Tags: android, android-layout, rolamento

Boa Noite a todos.

Estou com um simples `layout` que contem um `textView` para controlar o título e outro `textView` para controlar o conteúdo. O que ocorre é que já tentei por diversas vezes incluir um `ScrollView` apenas no segundo `textView` porém está acatando o `layout` inteiro, fazendo com que um texto sobreponha o outro ao utilizar o `Scroll`. Estou utilizando o `RelativeLayout`, pois com o `Linear` não tive sucesso na formatação correta.

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_activity_video03"
tools:context="luizugliano.com.br.appfilmes.ActivityVideo03">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Título"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="TextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXX"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem de colocar os atributos de posicionamento no ScrollView e não no TextView:

```
.........
.........
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="TextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXXTextoXXX"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"/>

</ScrollView>
```